# Page numbers appear only on chapter start pages. How to get them on all the pages

Tags: page-numbering, pagestyle

I know that `\pagestyle{empty}` put page numbers only on 1st page of the chapter. But I commented the same and I still don't get page numbers execpt on chapter's 1st page.

```
%This is the main file.  This is where you set up your preferences, name the packages you need, and use the "input" command to order the chapters and other major components of your thesis, most of which are set up as separate .tex files.  To see other project files, click the "Project" tab on the upper left.  If you click on a section in the pdf preview, you will jump to that file (Overleaf)
\documentclass[12pt]{report}  %12 point font is set - Times New Roman is the default

%These are a bunch of packages that may or may not be needed for features I use later
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\input{glossary}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} %margin of bound side 1.5 in, rest of margins 1 in, per Creighton Thesis guideline formats
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\widowpenalty10000% This automatically groups lines so there is at least 2 from each paragraph on a page.  Optional
\clubpenalty10000 %see above comment
\usepackage{indentfirst} %This makes the first paragraph of a section indented.  Optional.

\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{gensymb}

%To float image where the syntax is%
\usepackage{float}
%For algorithm%
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
%For theorem environment
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem} {Theorem}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\frenchspacing

\newpage
%\thispagestyle{empty}

\mbox{}
\clearpage %blank page at beginning of pdf.  not numbered

\input{approval} %Have this page printed and signed, then delete from your thesis and insert the signed version.

%\includepdf[scale=1.0]{Sig2.pdf} % After the dean signs the approval page, LuAnn Schwery sends you a pdf, which you insert into your thesis

\pagenumbering{roman} %begin roman numeral page numbers for the front matter
\input{cover} %title page

\doublespacing

\newpage %insert blank page, counted in page numbers
%\thispagestyle{empty} % do not display page number
\mbox{}
\clearpage 

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract} 
\input{abstract}  %Abstract is the first thing in the thesis after the title

\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
\input{acknowledgments} %optional

\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication
\input{dedication} %optional

\clearpage


\tableofcontents %automatically generate TOC
\clearpage

\listoftables %automatically generates list of tables
\clearpage
\listoffigures%automatically generates list of figures

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic} % start normal numbering on the first page of chapter 1
\input{chapter1}

\input{chapter2}

\input{chapter3}

\input{chapter4}

\input{chapter5}
\clearpage

\appendix %begin appendix section
\chapter{Style guide} \label{sec:appa}
\input{appendixa}
\clearpage



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  We can't see what's in your chapter files.  Please check to make sure that `\pagestyle{empty}` isn't in any of those files.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is somehow wrong : `\pagestyle{empty}` empties the regular header and footers. But `\chapter` in standard classes automatically issues a `\thispagestyle{plain}` for the page containing the chapter header, thus producing the page number in footer, whatever the previous `pagestyle{...}`

Hence if you want it on any page, simply use `\pagestyle{plain}`.

As you use the `report` class, you could opt for running headers produced with `\pagestyle{headers}`, where the page number is in the header, and the footer is empty, except for the chapter pages, obviously.